# Save two Entities from one View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

[image]How to save two Entities from one View. Suppose I have two Entities Party and Person with One to Many relation. Now I need to save both Entities from Party View. I am using ASP.NET MVC4.

```
public partial class Cm_Opt_Pty_Party_S
{
    public Cm_Opt_Pty_Party_S()
    {
        this.Cm_Opt_Psn_Person_S = new HashSet<Cm_Opt_Psn_Person_S>();
    }

    public int Pty_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Pty_PARTYTYPECODE { get; set; }
    public string Pty_FULLNAME { get; set; }
    public string Pty_GOVTID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Pty_GOVTIDTC { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Pty_GOVTIDSTAT { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cm_Opt_Psn_Person_S> Cm_Opt_Psn_Person_S { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We need more details than that. What is the problem you are having? what does `Party` and `Person` look like. Do you need shown to create a view model containing both entities?

Comment: see below answer i have added , it is my sample of code . here my person entity is related to party

Comment: Rather than post an answer you should edit your question. can you show your model? From what you said it sounded like a `Party` that contained a list of `Person`. What exactly is wrong with your code, are you getting an error? If so, what error? To get reasonable answers give all the details needed.

Comment: So in your view, do you have a `Cm_Opt_Pty_Party_S` and you are adding extra items to your Collection of `Cm_Opt_Psn_Person_S`, then trying to save that new Collection? Just to clarify. You still haven't actually said what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a `ViewModel` This class would contain the relevant properties needed to create both entities.

Then you base your `View` on the `ViewModel` instead, and pass that to the controller.

When you want to save the entities, you can build up the separate entities and save them.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better understanding of your issue, so editing this answer to show the solution I would use.

Your Controller will deliver the Party object to your view for displaying the `Party` information. Using a loop you can display the items contained in the collection.

```
@foreach(var m in Model.Persons)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model=>m.FirstName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model=>m.Surname)
}
```

When you want to add more items into the collection, you will need to render a partial view or new view containing a form for adding a `Person`. It will be strongly typed as `Person` model and the Controller action recieving the post will be expecting a `Person`

If for example a `Person` just had a `FirstName`,`Surname` and `PartyId` the form would use these helpers in your view

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.FirstName)
@Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Surname)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.PartyId)
```

You then submit that back to your controller, and have logic for adding the person to the collection. Then return the view with `Party` model containing the newly added Person in the `Persons` collection.

Using  `@Ajax.BeginForm` or some custom Jquery/Javascript you could handle this async to prevent page refreshing during the process.

If you don't want to do it this way, another option is EditorTemplates. See here for example: [ASP.NET MVC LIST and Create in same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084858/asp-net-mvc-list-and-create-in-same-view)

Comment: problem is here is that i have a Party that contained a list of Person. so how can i save data from party view. whatever you are written above is quite OK but it is for Display only, suppose i need to create new person. something like <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person_S.FIRSTNAME)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.FIRSTNAME)

                    </div>

Comment: but i cannot write like this way <div class="editor-field"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person_S.FIRSTNAME) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.FIRSTNAME) </div> because person is a Icollection .also i cannot loop otherwise it will create list of template html.

Comment: what is Persons.Person? here Persons is a collection but in this collection i don't have Person.

Comment: @Kashif Updated answer now I have a better view of your problem